# How do you find the longitudinal and cross sectional profiles of polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, bathymetry, profile, marine

I am currently carrying out a research project involving submarine canyons. The canyons are mapped as polygons and I need to find the longitudinal and cross sectional profiles of the canyons. Each canyon also has a centre line, mapped as a polyline.
I know you can draw individual profile lines, but I have over 200 canyons and this would be extremely time consuming!

Does anyone know how it can be done by a more efficient method?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201867/create-a-line-perpendicular-to-an-existing-line-in-arcgis/201871#201871