# Creating parallel line in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I would like to be able to create parallel lines with a defined distance, in the same way that the editor's parallel copy tool does.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find an answer at this link [Creating parallel line in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224637/creating-parallel-line-in-arcgis-pro-using-arcpy)