# Creating parallel lines in Geographic Coordinate System using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, line

I have a polyline feature class that is using GCS_WGS_1984 (code 4326). I am trying to create lines that are parallel to a polyline from this feature class at distance d.

From some searching, I've only been able to find out how to create parallel lines here:

[Creating parallel line in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224637/creating-parallel-line-in-arcgis-pro-using-arcpy)

but it only works for 2D:

```
import arcpy, math
infc=r'..\SCRARCH\clone.shp'

def CopyParallel(plyP,sLength):
    part=plyP.getPart(0)
    lArray=arcpy.Array();rArray=arcpy.Array()
    for ptX in part:
        dL=plyP.measureOnLine(ptX)
        ptX0=plyP.positionAlongLine (dL-0.01).firstPoint
        ptX1=plyP.positionAlongLine (dL+0.01).firstPoint
        dX=float(ptX1.X)-float(ptX0.X)
        dY=float(ptX1.Y)-float(ptX0.Y)
        lenV=math.hypot(dX,dY)
        sX=-dY*sLength/lenV;sY=dX*sLength/lenV
        leftP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X+sX,ptX.Y+sY)
        lArray.add(leftP)
        rightP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X-sX, ptX.Y-sY)
        rArray.add(rightP)
    array = arcpy.Array([lArray, rArray])
    section=arcpy.Polyline(array)
    return section


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,("Shape@","Width")) as cursor:
    for shp,w in cursor:
        twoLines=CopyParallel(shp,w)
        cursor.updateRow((twoLines,w))
```

I have tried first projecting to spatial reference code 3857, then running the above code, then converting back. However, there is some distortion (~8% error).

Is there a solution that would work for geographic coordinate systems?

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the source.

Comment: I've added the source

Comment: Spatial references with projected and geographic coordinate systems *should* behave very differently. Doing Cartesian math on a geographic CS does not work, and no distance measurement should ever be trusted in Web Mercator.  ArcPy provides the tools to perform the Forward and Inverse geodetic problems (`PointGeometry` methods `pointFromAngleAndDistance ()` and `angleAndDistanceTo()`, respectively), or you can project to an appropriate projection, then project back). Note that the parallel lines will not *look* parallel in a GCS (and you may need to densify the line first).

Comment: Ok. I removed my downvote.

Comment: hi @Vince, can you elaborate on why there may be a need to densify?

Comment: @sdMarth A 'line' that is straight in one CRS may not be straight in another CRS. This affects longer lines more, of course, and is generally more true for east-west lines.