# Converting two parallel lines into single parts

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, line

I need to create one parallel line for each of my 800 line segments and used [this method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224637/creating-parallel-line-in-arcgis-pro-using-arcpy) (code below) to successfully create two parallels. The answer mentions the need to separate them into separate parts but doesn't explain how. How can I convert these into one single parallel for each original polyline?

```
import arcpy, math
infc=r'..\SCRARCH\clone.shp'

def CopyParallel(plyP,sLength):
    part=plyP.getPart(0)
    lArray=arcpy.Array();rArray=arcpy.Array()
    for ptX in part:
        dL=plyP.measureOnLine(ptX)
        ptX0=plyP.positionAlongLine (dL-0.01).firstPoint
        ptX1=plyP.positionAlongLine (dL+0.01).firstPoint
        dX=float(ptX1.X)-float(ptX0.X)
        dY=float(ptX1.Y)-float(ptX0.Y)
        lenV=math.hypot(dX,dY)
        sX=-dY*sLength/lenV;sY=dX*sLength/lenV
        leftP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X+sX,ptX.Y+sY)
        lArray.add(leftP)
        rightP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X-sX, ptX.Y-sY)
        rArray.add(rightP)
    array = arcpy.Array([lArray, rArray])
    section=arcpy.Polyline(array)
    return section


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,("Shape@","Width")) as cursor:
    for shp,w in cursor:
        twoLines=CopyParallel(shp,w)
        cursor.updateRow((twoLines,w))
```

Edited to show a screenshot of what I'm working with. Black is original lines and purple are the offset parallels.
[image]

Comment: Are the parallell line pairs touching eachother?

Comment: The lines are not touching their own pairs, although some are intersecting other lines. Edited to add screenshot.

Comment: I would try [Multipart To Singlepart](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm)

Comment: That works to make everything a single part. I should clarify I only want one of these parallels for each original line to remain. How should I go about deleting one of each pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove from the script the part that creates ones of the parallels and you are done.

I will start working removing this:

```
rightP=arcpy.Point(ptX.X-sX, ptX.Y-sY)
        rArray.add(rightP)
```

to prevent the creation of the "right parallel"