# Generate a polygon based on 2 points along an axis

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, linear-referencing

I have a polygon feature, inside it, 2 points along an axis.

[image]

I draw a line perpendicular to the axis (where the points are) until I intersect the border of the polygon, to get the 4 “sides” of the polygon I am looking for.

[image]

And ideally, I wanted to get this directly through “arcpy”.

What’s the best way to obtain this? The solutions I am thinking of, are way too complicated and/or not precise enough.

I am probably missing something there.

Comment: See how to create perpendiculars http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201867/create-a-line-perpendicular-to-an-existing-line-in-arcgis/201871#201871 use feature to polygon after that. Removing unwanted polygons can be tricky, but possible

Comment: Thanks for your post, this is bringing me some new perspectives for my final solution :-)

Comment: Once you have made an attempt on your own code be sure to post it here, and flag to have your question re-opened, if you need more help.

Comment: The question is closed for me (can't select @FelixIP 's answer as accepted answer). 
Here is my "pseudo-code": assuming the points are already defined, I follow the Felixp 's link: buffer the point / clip the axis and the points (then multipart to single part) / define their perpendiculars (but way smaller as described in the link, 0.4 not 1000). Merge the result with geometry (transformed in lines with polygons to lines), extend the lines, then feature to polygons. 
“Select by location” between the new feature class and the first extended line, then the second and cross the results