# Splitting Polygons at midpoint using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, splitting

I'm attempting to split around 4000 polygons at their midpoint, perpendicular to their longest axis (ie across the width at the midpoint), as in the diagram below.

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to do this automatically and avoid manually splitting each polygon. I have extracted the midpoint of polygons by converting the longest lines that can be drawn in each, I just need to determine a method to draw a width line across this point automatically.

Polygons vary in their width, and hence tools which split polygons by defining width lines of a certain length isn't really what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: are all the polygons convex?

Comment: Yes, they are more or less shaped similar to that shown in the above diagram.

Comment: Create perpendicular as described http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201867/create-a-line-perpendicular-to-an-existing-line-in-arcgis/201871#201871 Use use them and original as inputs for feature to polygon. It will help to do near on points to boundaries

Answer (score 26):

Script below will output a new feature class of split polygons and the lines used for splitting them. Advanced license is required.

The polygons will be split like this:
[image]

[image]

Using Centroid of Minimum Bounding Geometry rectangle as midpoint and split across the rectangle.

```
import arcpy
print 'Running'
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\TEST.gdb'    #Change to match your data
infc = r'polygons123'                   #Change to match your data
outfc_splitlines = r'splitlines'        
outfc_splitpolygons=r'splitpolygons'    

spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(infc).spatialReference
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace, out_name=outfc_splitlines, geometry_type='POLYLINE',spatial_reference=spatial_ref) #Creates a new feature class to hold the split lines

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc,['SHAPE@','SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']) as cursor: #For each input polygon create a minimum bounding rectangle
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(row[0],r'in_memory\bounding','RECTANGLE_BY_WIDTH')
        arcpy.SplitLine_management(r'in_memory\bounding', r'in_memory\splitline') #Split the rectangle into four lines, one for each side
        linelist=[]
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'in_memory\splitline',['SHAPE@LENGTH','SHAPE@']) as cursor2:
            for row2 in cursor2:
                linelist.append(row2) #Store the lines lenghts and geometries in a list
            linelist=sorted(linelist,key=lambda x: x[0]) #Sort shortest to longest (the two shortest sides of the rectangles come first and second in list)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features=linelist[0][1], out_feature_class=r'in_memory\templine') #Copy the first line to memory
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(r'in_memory\templine',['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y']) as cursor3:
            for row3 in cursor3:
                newcentroidx=row[1] #Find x coord of bounding rectangle centroid
                newcentroidy=row[2] #Find y..
                row3[0]=newcentroidx #Assign this to the shortest line
                row3[1]=newcentroidy #Assign this to the shortest line
                cursor3.updateRow(row3) #Move the line to the centroid of bounding rectangle
        arcpy.Append_management(inputs=r'in_memory\templine', target=outfc_splitlines) #Save this line in splitline feature class
#After all split lines are created convert input polygons to lines, merge with split lines and create new polygons from lines.

arcpy.FeatureToLine_management(in_features=infc, out_feature_class=r'in_memory\polytemp')
arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=[r'in_memory\polytemp',outfc_splitlines], output=r'in_memory\templines')
arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(in_features=r'in_memory\templines', out_feature_class=outfc_splitpolygons)
print 'Done'
```

[image]

Attributes will get lost but you can use Spatial Join to add them again.

Comment: Great solution.  I think it should be noted that the Advanced license is required to perform this operation (splitline, featureToLine and featureToPolygon).  Further, I think adding some comments throughout your code will help new python users understand what each line is doing.

Comment: Hi @BERA, sorry for the slow reply. Script doesn't seem to work, outputting the following error: ERROR 000466: in_memory\templine does not match the schema of target splitlines
Failed to execute (Append).

Comment: Try to change the append line to: arcpy.Append_management(inputs=r'in_memory\templine', target=outfc_splitlines, schema_type='NO_TEST')

Comment: Seem to get another error, this time: Parsing error IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (line 28)

Comment: You need to have 8 spaces before the arcpy.Append_manag...

Comment: Yes, indentation is a big problem with python