# Create line segment at point perpendicular to line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6

I have a long road with 50+ points on it to mark the drainage pipes that go under the road. However, the pipes are not points, they are long cylinders. They are (almost) always perpendicular to the road. Is there a way to turn each point in to a 20 meter line which is perpendicular to the road? I would at the same time like to preserve some of the attribute fields in the point, where the diameter of the pipe is specified. This can of course be done using a spatial join later.

I have tried creating the line features myself in Editor mode, using the Constrain Perpendicular function on the Feature Construction toolbar. But doing this manually takes too long (there are more roads with even more drainage pipe points).

The pink lines are how I imagine the output to be:

[image: road in black, drainage points in blue and pink lines how I image the drainage lines to be]

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 and ArcGIS Pro 2.4. I am not yet well-versed in Python.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201867/create-a-line-perpendicular-to-an-existing-line-in-arcgis/201871#201871

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP, could unfortunately not make this solution work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for me was to use the [Draw perpendicular line segments between points to polylines tool](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0a4892bd754146e48b87de2352cdf64d).