# Create a line on a midpoint of another polyline at a certain angle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a polyline layer, for each feature I want to create a mid point of the polyline (which is easy enough to do) and then generate a polyline of a certain distance at a right angle of the feature. I have used the code from the following [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/201875/4750) which has generated a line but not what I was expecting.

What I would like to generate is something along these lines (in purple). The red is what the code generated.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you know the length of each line? Stored as an attribute?

Comment: @BERA The Purple line will be 12 metres, so 6 metres on each side

Comment: I am using solution from that post on a weekly basis long before I posted it 4 years ago till now. Perhaps check your data. Are your lines single part? Projected? Derived from raster without simplification?

Comment: Also check if your original buffer is small enough, unless your are using @Paul solution.